# System Backup Image in DVD

Tags: 12.10, dvd-backup

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 installed alongside with Windows 7. Can I just have a system backup in the form of one or more DVD(s) so that I can restore the system with every package that are previously installed and if possible can I make use of that DVD(s) as a live CD with all the previously installed packages?

If "Back In Time(root)" is installed in my system, will it be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use something like [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) to backup your ubuntu installed software. Another option is to generate a list of the software like this....

```
aptitude search -F '%100p' '~i!~M' > my-styff
```

copy it to a flash drive and/or email it to yourself. Saves lots of space as long as you are talking about standard install stuff.

Comment: Can you tell little bit more in detail about Clonezilla?

As per the link you suggested Clonezilla live is what I require. But I dunno how to install and make use of it. Google gives result about the Clonezilla server. What is Clonezilla server now?